# how to filter file by file's type in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I am developing an iOS app. The problem is filter the files by type. I only want to filter the type of  *note* file. who can help me, I am new to Objective C. So I wish you can tell me in detail. Thank you !

this is more information. the files are attachments,when i upload a attachment in my app,my attachment icon will show the number attachment.if i click the icon it will show me the attachment which i up load. But there is a bug ,if my attachment`s type is image,doc,... the app will be ok,but if the type is note my app will be crash. So i want to filter the file which type is note

Comment: where are those files? in the bundle? in the `Documents` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method `[self findFiles:@"note"]`:

```
-(NSArray *)findFiles:(NSString *)extension{    
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSFileManager *fManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *item;
    NSArray *contents = [fManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] error:nil];

    for (item in contents){
        if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
            [matches addObject:item];
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```